# How to set Terminal Initial Working Directory for all workspaces in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, terminal, configuration

The default working directory in Eclipse for **Terminal** is User Home.

I adopted a strategy a few years ago that consistis of using many workspaces with Eclipse for organizational purposes.

Also, I use Terminal tool a lot, but I have to set its initial working directory everytime I create a new workspace.

How can I change the **Terminal Initial Working Directory** once and for all so that it will be applied to **all workspaces** in the future?

[image]